# Update UITableView from API - performance issue

Tags: iphone, performance, uitableview

I have a UITableView thats loaded from an API call - the performance of this is fine.

However each cell that loads also requires an individual API call to fill it out with more information. I'm finding that this causes the UITableView to "stutter" when scrolling?

What is the best way to implement the additional API calls to prevent the "stuttering"?

I'm thinking of using NSThreads (something along the lines of the solution mentioned here: http://probablyinteractive.com/2009/3/19/Truckloads.html ), but this is proving to be pretty complex.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [`NSOperationQueue`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html) instead of managing your own threads. Might make things less complex.